# Correct HTML5 (+ schema.org) mark up for an article's publication date and location

Tags: html, css, schema.org

The HTML `<time>` element represents either a time on a 24-hour clock or a precise date in the Gregorian calendar (with optional time and timezone information).

For instance:

```
<q>All is quiet on <time datetime="2018-01-01 00:00">New Year's Day</time></q>
```

---

With this in mind, `<time>` seems the obvious markup for giving *article publication dates and times*:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<h2>Article Heading Here</h2>
<time datetime="2017-10-30" itemprop="datePublished">October 30th, 2017</time>
<p>Article Here</p>
</article>
```

---

Often though, articles will give a *reporting location* alongside their publication date and time.

But a stated geographical location seems like inappropriate content for `<time>`.

So... how best to mark up the information:

**Huddersfield • October 30th, 2017**

---

My favoured approach so far is to use an HTML5 `data-*` element, displayed via the CSS `::before` pseudo-element:

**Working Example:**

```css
time::before {
content: attr(data-location) '\00a0\00a0\2022\00a0\00a0';
}
```

```html
<time datetime="2017-10-30" itemprop="datePublished" data-location="Huddersfield">October 30th, 2017</time>
```

But is there a more semantic approach (using schema.org microdata etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a [dateline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dateline) is typically used for news articles, Schema.org defines a [`dateline`](http://schema.org/dateline) property only for [`NewsArticle`](http://schema.org/NewsArticle) (which is a sub-type of `Article`):

> A dateline is a brief piece of text included in news articles that describes where and when the story was written or filed though the date is often omitted. Sometimes only a placename is provided.

It expects a text value.

#### Examples in Microdata

The dateline consists of placename and date (assuming that the publishing date is the date "when the story was written or filed"):

```html
<p itemprop="dateline">
  Huddersfield • <time datetime="2017-10-30" itemprop="datePublished">October 30th, 2017</time>
</p>
```

The dateline consists of placename only:

```html
<p>
  <span itemprop="dateline">Huddersfield</span> • <time datetime="2017-10-30" itemprop="datePublished">October 30th, 2017</time>
</p>
```